# Problem monitoring directory for file activity in VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to write a simple program to monitor a folder for new files in VB.NET 2010, and am having some trouble.

Here's a simplified version of what my program looks like:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Main
    Public fileWatcher As FileSystemWatcher

    Sub btnGo_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
        '//# initialize my FileSystemWatcher to monitor a particular directory for new files
        fileWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
        fileWatcher.Path = thisIsAValidPath.ToString()
        fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
        AddHandler fileWatcher.Created, AddressOf fileCreated
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub fileCreated(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        '//# program does not exit when I comment the line below out
        txtLatestAddedFilePath.Text = e.FullPath
        '//# e.FullPath is valid when I set a breakpoint here, but when I step into the next line, the program abruptly halts with no error code that I can see
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, I have a button which will initialize a FileSystemWatcher when clicked. The initialization works, and when I place a new file in the monitored directory, the program reaches the `fileCreated` sub. I can even see that `e.FullPath` is set correctly. However, it exits abruptly right after that with no error code (none that I can see, anyways). If I comment everything in the `fileCreated` sub out, the program continues running as expected.

Any ideas as to why it's dying on me? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to VS/VB.NET, so maybe I'm just making a silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be a cross-thread operation exception.

Try this:

```
Private Sub fileCreated(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
  me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Function() txtLatestAddedFilePath.Text = e.FullPath))
End Sub
```

or (even better in your context), during fileWatcher initialization:

```
fileWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
fileWatcher.SynchronizingObject = me
[...]
```

---

Explanation:

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/FileSystemWatcher.aspx (see *Preventing Cross-Thread Operations*)

Excerpt:

> By default, when the FileSystemWatcher
>   object raises notification events, the
>   delegate calls are made on a thread
>   from the system thread pool. This will
>   generally not be the same thread as
>   that being used to control the form.
>   As the demonstration application will
>   require that the file changes be
>   logged within a visual element of the
>   form, using the allocated thread to
>   modify the list box contents would
>   result in a cross-threading operation
>   and an IllegalOperationException being
>   thrown.

Comment: Aha, it was a cross-threading issue. Your solution worked perfectly, thanks!